# Convergence in measure of sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Hi I don't have a lot of experience in measure theory so that might be basic. If you have a sequence of functions $a_{k}(x): \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$0 \leq\limsup\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty}\int_{\Omega}a_{k}(x)dx \leq 0$$ How does this imply that $a_{k}(x) \rightarrow 0$ in measure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the statement is not correct. Simply consider $a_k := a$ for some $a: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\int_{\Omega} a(x) \, dx=0.$$

However, the statement is correct if $a_k$ is a sequence of **non-negative** functions as the following proof shows:

*Proof:* Let $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of non-negative functions and denote by $\lambda$ the Lebesge measure. From

$$0 \leq \liminf_{k \to \infty} \int_{\Omega} a_k(x) \, \lambda(dx) \leq \limsup_{k \to \infty} \int_{\Omega} a_k(x) \, \lambda(dx) \leq 0$$

it follows that the limit $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{\Omega} a_k(x) \, \lambda(dx)$$ (exists and) equals $0$. This means that $a_k$ converges in $L^1$ to $0$. On the other hand, Markov's inequality implies

$$\begin{align*} \lambda(\{x \in \Omega; |a_k(x)| \geq \varepsilon\} &= \lambda(\{x \in \Omega; a_k(x) \geq \varepsilon\}) \\ &\leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int_{\Omega} a_k(x) \, dx. \end{align*}$$

Letting $k \to \infty$, we see that the left-hand side converges to $0$. Hence, $a_k \to 0$ in measure.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you explain how it shows convergence in measure for non-negative functions, given that convergence in measure is defined as [wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure).

Comment: @Moses I have just added the proof to my answer.

Comment: Hi @saz, could you explain how you got the last inequality please. The $\lambda(\{x \in \Omega; a_{k}(x) \geq \epsilon \})) \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{\Omega}a_{k}(x)dx$, it is from markov inequality as you stated I assume. From the wiki entry 'Markov inequality' it states that it is for an extended real valued function, what if the function is not an extended real valued function, can it still be applied?

Comment: @saz Does Markov inequality hold for any measurable real valued function?

Comment: @JohnJack Yes. It holds for any non-negative measurable function $f$ that $$\lambda(|f| \geq \varepsilon) \leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int |f| \, d\lambda.$$

Comment: @saz Thanks. If you have a chance check out [my bounty question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054652/condition-on-vector-valued-function).